# can't reference firebase database in applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update my firebase database before the app being forced to close to no avail.

Settings:

- Xcode Version: 8.2.1
- ios simulator
- `Info.plist` > `Application does not run in background`: `Bool` `YES`

Simulate:

1. Launch application
2. Close application via Hardware > Home on simulator

Code: `AppDelegate.swift`

this updates

```
 func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("status").child(user.uid).setValue("foobar")
}
```

this does not update (print is functioning)

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("applicationWillTerminate")
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("status").child(user.uid).setValue("foobar")
}
```

Here is  screenshot of my db structure
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKju6.png)

Since I  have 5 seconds to execute an asynchronous task, I feel like it should work

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to
>   perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before
>   time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

any clues?

Comment: Can you add to post your "status" database structure? Screenshot for example

Comment: The database operation probably submits an asynchronous task but your app is being terminated before it completes.  I would not rely on any network operations in `applicationWillTerminate`

Comment: You can't send any requests on `applicationWillTerminate` I have tried before but to no avail did I become successful

Comment: @VladPulichev https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKju6.png

Comment: @Paulw11 I understand that but I feel like it conflicts with the following: 
`Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.`

Comment: @ZonilyJame any ideas on why it may not? is it a bug?

Comment: @kurifu I think it's not a bug. It's just that apple may still not be allowing us to do api calls on `applicationWillTerminate`, but I'm just a junior iOS dev and only have a year or so experience, so I'm not really a hundred percent sure.

Comment: Anyway I've researched this topic before  and it seems that it's just best to do async tasks on `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillEnterBackground` for the time being.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Tried to update a value in FIRDatebase, nothing happened. so no api calls will executed in applicationWillTerminate??